# Joomla 2.5 Loading javaScript Files inside default.php

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I was making a component in joomla 2.5  Which contains a default view.html and a tmpl/default.php as an layout file I need to add some javascript code into the default.php file and I added this Using the

```
    $document->addScript(JURI::base() . "components/com_mycomp/javascript/myfile1.js");
    $document->addScript(JURI::base() . "components/com_mycomp/javascript/myfile11.js");
    $document->addScript(JURI::base() . "components/com_mycomp/javascript/myfile12.js");
```

it was working fine ( I tried it by adding a document.write() inside every js) , But the problem is I have a code inside my default.php inside

```
   <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="components/com_mycomp/myfile3.js"><\/script>');</script>
```

I tried to print it inside  but nothing works so far...
I also tried using the JURI::base. "path" inside php tags

Am I doing It all wrong? How can I do it in joomla way
Help and advices needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

three's no need to add it using `document.write`. To import scrip file correctly, you can either do it using your first approach, or using the `JHtml` method like so:

```
JHtml::_('script', 'components/com_mycomp/javascript/myfile1.js');
JHtml::_('script', 'components/com_mycomp/javascript/myfile11.js');
JHtml::_('script', 'components/com_mycomp/javascript/myfile12.js');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. But my template dosen't show up anything How will I debug it in joomla 2.5??

Comment: Ok firstly, ensure you're using Joomla 2.5.27 (latest version) just to be on the safe side. Then refresh the page and open your browser console to check for any errors

Comment: ya I have two errors in the console one Uncaught typeError and one Uncaught Reference error , but the files are(js+css+html) working perfectly outside joomla, I am using 2.5.16

Comment: in firefox it shows as 'ReferenceError: $ is not defined ,
TypeError: router is undefined '

Comment: The errors are gone when I changed the loading order of the javascript files, but still now 'null' is showing in my view insted of showing two buttons

Comment: Thaks for valuable time .. Its working now, I neede to call a method inside js from html body onload..